# wrong calculations with single values

Tags: vb.net

I have a strange situation :

This is my code :

```
dim vl1,vl2,vl3 as single

vl1=26,999.99

vl2=27,000

vl3=vl1-vl2
```

Now I expect that the value on `vl3` will be `-0.01`

But the value on `vl3` is `-0.009765625`.

Why ?

I try also

```
Messagebox.Show(26,999.99-27,000)
```

and the value that is shown is the same as above.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html

Comment: Try `Double` or better yet, `Decimal` if it is currency

Comment: Is that valid syntax?  I didn't think you could put a thousands separator in a value when assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim vl1, vl2, vl3 As Decimal

    vl1 = 26999.99D
    vl2 = 27000D

    vl3 = vl1 - vl2

End Sub
```

Your data type `Single` does not have enough precision (digits) to account for 0.01 out of 27000

**Edit 1**

Then try the operation in `Decimal` by with conversions

```
    Dim vl1, vl2, vl3 As Single

    vl1 = 26999.99  'Get from SQL
    vl2 = 27000     'Get from SQL

    vl3 = CSng(CDec(vl1) - CDec(vl2))
    ' Sent to SQL
```

Comment: I post this code only as a sample ( that show the same problem that I have in my real application).

in my real application , I have to get the values vl1 and vl2 from a sql server database ( the corresponding fields on database are configured as real).

Now , I get the 2 values ( in single variables )  , and I try to get the difference in vl3 ( single).

And after I should put the vl3 in another field in database (real type).

how can I resolve this with Decimal variable in vb.net ?

Comment: My application is a financial application.So in this case do you have any suggestions about data types that should I use in sql server and inside VB ? I know that decimal data type use more bits than real in sql server ?

Comment: `Decimal` is the way to go with financial data. That is the reason it is there.